# HTML Codes in CakePHP $html->link function

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink

This code

```
 $html->link(" &raquo;", '/events/view/'.$event['Event']['id']), array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'more') )
```

Outputs

```
<a href="/events/view/4"> &amp;raquo;</a>
```

instead of >>

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you have syntax error instead you should have:

```
$this->Html->link(" &raquo;", '/events/view/'.$event['Event']['id'], array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'more') );
```

At least that's what I see.

Comment: Thank Nik, it's a matter of ) :D